# grep command working in testdir but not in "real" directory

Tags: linux, grep, filenames

I just thought I had found my solution because the command works in my test directory.

```
grep -H -e 'author="[^"].*' *.xml | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -I '{}' mv {} mydir/.
```

But using the command in the non-test-direcory the command did not work:
This is the error message:

```
grep: unknown option -- O
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Not even this worked:

```
$ grep -H author *.xml
```

or this:

```
$ grep -H 'author' *.xml
```

(same error message)

I suspect it has some relation to the file names or the amount of files. 
I have almost 3000 files in the non-test-directory and only 20 in my test directory.
In both directories almost all file names contain spaces and " - ".

Some more info:

- I'm using Cygwin.
- I am not allowed to change the filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated):

```
grep -HlZ 'author="[^"].*' -- *.xml | xargs -0 -I {} mv -- {} mydir/
```

*EXPLANATION* (updated)

- In your "real" directory you have a file with name starting with `-O`.
  Your shell expands the file list `*.xml` and `grep` takes your `-` starting filename as an option (not valid). Same thing happens with `mv`. As explained in the `Common options` section of `info coreutils`, you can use `--` to delimit the option list. What comes after `--` is considered as an operand, not an option.
- Using the `-l` (lowercase L) option, `grep` outputs only the filename of matching files, so you don't need to use `cut`.
- To correctly handle every strange filename, you have to use the pair `-Z` in `grep` and `-0` in `xargs`.
- No need to use `-e` because your pattern does not begin with `-`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good advice!
A part of the problem is at least solved now.

God news: grep does not complain and it finds one file (with this horrible name):
!! Importing device - to be finished later.xml

Bad news: grep does not list all files containing the searched string - for example these files beginning with single dash, duouble dash and triple underscore:
-OFF.xml
--operation.xml
___Checklist - menu.xml

Should I maybe do something with the variable IFS?

/ T

Comment: @Tony: I think `grep` lists those files, the problem is `mv`. You must do the `--` trick with `mv` too. Now I'll edit the answer to fix the issue. If it works please accept my answer! :)

Comment: @Tony: great you liked my answer... please remember to set my answer as accepted! :)